# Implementing Airbrake into a ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, airbrake

I have an older `.NET 4.8` project that needs to use Airbrake. The project is using `Unity` for its `IoC` container, implementing the standard `Repository Service` pattern.

There's very little in the way of ASP.NET examples.

I am looking to do something like this:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(ILogger<>));
    container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService();
}

public class MyController
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    
    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger, IMyService _myService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var x = _myService.DoThis();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe I need to either somehow register Airbrake with ILogger or perhaps create my own logging service.

```
public class Logging : ILogging
{
    public void LogError(Exception e, string message)
    {
        var airbrake = new AirbrakeNotifier(new AirbrakeConfig
        {
            ProjectId = // pulled from web.config somehow
            ProjectKey = // pulled from web.config somehow
        });

        var notice = airbrake.BuildNotice(ex);
        airbrake.NotifyAsync(notice).Result;
    }
}
```

I have tried using this as starting point: https://github.com/airbrake/sharpbrake/blob/master/docs/asp-net-http-module.md

This is excellent, but I need to extend it somehow to be able to use it within my services and not just the .Web project.

I know there's the ASP.NET module that will automatically capture the errors but I am wanting to manually log when I see fit, and avoid having to call the airbrake client every time I want to log an error.

Is there a way to do this or am I completely misunderstanding how this should be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to wire it up as part of the .NET ILogger. I am sure there is a way (probably via OWIN) but you nothing stops you from writing a basic logging service as you would any other service and using that via bog standard DI. The answer was pretty much in the question to begin with.